# Adding a route to match a specific pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a controller in Ruby on Rails and I would like to do the following:

When a user is trying to access the controller I want to match some parameters. For example

```
domain.com/hello/19213/sayHello
```

I want to translate this to:

```
domain.com/hello/:id/:method
```

in my routes files.

Keep in mind that :method parameter might not exist but :id will always be there.

In addition if it is possible I would like to match the specific :method with a method in my controller. If not I plan to use a switch case.

Can someone provide an example for this and what I have to put in my routes.rb?

I found this:

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

But I believe that this is somehow different as I only want to match router for the specific controller not every controller in my project.

Thanks

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: The only relevant action that I found in here is 3.11 Route Globbing
Route globbing is a way to specify that a particular parameter should be matched to all the remaining parts of a route. For example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By method, I assume you mean a method you have in your model. If that is the case, I believe you want something like this in your routes.rb

```
match ':controller/:id(/:method)'
```

The parentheses around :method mean that it is optional.

If you do not include a method, it will evaluate your SHOW action with params[:id] = :id

If you do include a method, it will evaluate the :method with params[:id] = :id

This is for methods you have defined in your controller

Comment: I assume you mean a method you have in your model. - I want the :method to be in the controller not the model. Is that possible? Is it the same?

Comment: It is not the same. Methods in the controller are things like show, index, new, create, update. Rails has standard ways of handling these types of methods.

For example, if you type domain.com/hello/1, that will perform the SHOW action in the hello controller, with params[:id]=1.

I encourage you to look at the Rails guide on routes, as it was very helpful to me when I was learning this stuff (especially the table at the end of section 2.2) - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Yes, I already know that. But what if I have a method called sayHello in my controller and I want to match it in the routes to work like edit.. domain.com/hello/id/sayHello . That was the question. Similar to domain.com/hello/id/edit. GET /photos/:id/edit edit return an HTML form for editing a photo Something similar to that. But using my own method in controller instead of edit!

Comment: @ntenisOT your last comment is correct. I have edited my answer for clarity.